# FileNet - Reporting total number of user logged in to Filenet during a given period of time

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

We need to report the total number of users those have logged into the Filenet environment during every quarter. Is there a way to do it?

I have seen an environment where a custom logon event was created. Whenever a user logs on this event will be raised and a custom entry may go into a staging DB from where the reports can be generated.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm right about this, but I don't think there is a way to audit logon events, at least there is nothing in the P8 KC. And I would say this is because of the way the CE works, the JAAS context is actually built against the server, then calls are just authenticated and authorized, there isn't really a logon phase.

However, what I'm sure of, is that it is definitely doable on the application side because there, there is a logon action initiated by the user. How do your user connect to your platform? Are they using Content Navigator, Workplace XT, a custom application you developed or the Java API, or maybe all of them? Please provide more context.

For instance, if they are using Content Navigator, then a simple plugin listening for the login event and logging this event would to the trick.

Comment: Users log into FileNet using Workplace XT and ICN.

Comment: Then I would go with logging on the application side. That means creating a plugin for ICN that listens the desktop onLogin function (and call a service to log in DB or somewhere else) and modifying the login page for the Workplace XT (which might be a bit more of a headache).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually CE hase not rise events about Log-In or Log-Out, cause of authorization proceeds on Application Server-side not in CE.

You have few options to create login events to collect it into some database and create the report:
1. create custom filter for client side and embed it into your client application for handle log-in / log-out events.
2. create custom LoginModule and configure it for FN CE application and handle events
3. try to look for the VW_VWUserLoginMsg event in PE (see docs:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.pe.user.doc/bpfes004.htm?lang=en) but you should use CaseAnalyser or create custom reporting.
4.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install IBM System Dashboard 5.0.0.2 from Fixpack central, use the Usage Reporter or the IBM License Monitoring Tool (ILMT) depending on the version. You'll need to run the Usage Collector (or IlmtCollector) monthly for IlmtReporter to give you the maximum user counts for the year - You're suppose to submit the report annually as part of the IBM Licensing agreement. IBM will periodically ask or audit customers for this information.